# How do I switch default directory for Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server

I'm trying to modify the default directory for Apache from /var/www to /var/www/public_html, and I can't find any resources specifically on how to do this. The httpd.conf and apache.conf files are empty. How would I go about this?

Comment: Is [`DocumentRoot` - Apache HTTP Server documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some apache builds, the default site is defined, not in the `httpd.conf` file, but in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`.  Take a look there.

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6362886) question over at SO should get you moving in the right direction.  The answer over there offers a basic virtualhost definition as well as a couple other things necessary to configure a site defined in `sites-available`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mywebserver.com
    DocumentRoot /home/www/public_html/
    <Directory /home/www/public_html/>
        Options None
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```